# Homework - Printing lines of a file between two line numbers

Tags: python, file, line

Using Python, how do I print the lines of a text file, given a starting and ending line number?

I have come up with a function, but this doesn't work.

```
def printPart(src, des, varFile):
    returnLines = ""
    for curLine in range(src, des):
        returnLines += linecache.getline(varFile, curLine)
    return returnLines
```

Comment: please, fix the indentation in your example; makes my eyes hurt...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since file objects are iterable in Python, you can apply all the functions from `itertools` to them.  Have a look at `itertools.islice()`.  (Since this is homework, I'll leave the details to you.)

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the first line in the file, using `readline()` reading each line counting `count += 1`. once count gets to the start line number, start printing. Once it gets to the last line number, `sys.exit()`